# A PC boots using the "with upstart" option, but not with the default option (systemd) - is this a reportable bug?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, upstart, systemd, bug-reporting

My Dell 755 PC with 16.04 (and a dual-boot of Windows 10) has a problem. It started right after some updates that required a reboot to complete.

My question is, is this a reportable bug, considering the symptoms below? If so what should be in the report?

Of course, advice about diagnosing and fixing my system also is welcome.

Symptoms:

- If I boot into the default Ubuntu option of the GRUB menu, it hangs a long time after checking or fixing lost inodes on sda3, and eventually reboots into emergency mode.
- If I boot into the "upstart" option in the "advanced" submenu in GRUB, it boots fine.
- The one time that I did a `journalctl -xb` during the problem, it showed that my system disk (sda3) had timed out. After a successful boot, the command shows nothing.
- The PC boots Windows 10 OK. (It's dual boot). The PC boots a live DVD of 16.04 fine and the drives can be mounted r/w without errors.
- GSmartControl shows no new errors, and runs tests with no errors.

#### Diagnostic/config info, per first comment:

sda3, sda5, and sda6 are all Logical partitions on the same Primary partition, which begins at roughly the "middle" of the hard drive, after the Windows 10 partition.

I have no reason to think the drive is failing except the timeout in systemd. Once it boots, in either Ubuntu or Win10, there are no hardware errors or odd symptoms.

```
i@memine-755:~$ sudo cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>         <mount point>           <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#
# / is on /dev/sda3 Jan2017
UUID=e1995ccc-4c3a-45f2-a3b5-41e6b09280f8 /                 ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
#
# /home is on /dev/sda5  Jan2017
UUID=d381bb29-4376-4c46-ab65-bf922f3be7a9 /home             ext4    defaults        0       2
#
# swap is on /dev/sda6  Jan2017
UUID=dda8beaa-2c0a-451d-a390-e5a82c6a4ce8 none              swap    sw              0       0
#
# Not Mountable  Jan2017    /dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="AA0673D90673A54B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="23a841d3-01"
# Win10 360GB Jan2017       /dev/sda2: UUID="C80277B30277A4DA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="23a841d3-02"
#
# partition on 2TB Hitachi drive (now on USB) is Hitachi50G (a primary ptn). /dev/sdd1 Jan2017       
# Use noAuto: Allow Ubuntu to mount via daemon, or manually,
# without possibly booting to emergency mode if disk is not present
UUID=fb436ad0-4513-4091-bdf3-094028b0104e /media/rich/Hitachi50G ext4 noauto,user,exec,sync,rw,errors=remount-ro  0 3 
#
# 
# partition on 2TB Hitachi drive (now on USB in enclosure) 
# is Hitachi180G (a logical ptn) (actually 1.8 TB).  /dev/sdd5 Jan2017.
# Use noAuto: Allow Ubuntu to mount via daemon, or manually,
# without possibly booting to emergency mode if disk is not present
UUID=eb733d8f-6208-4b71-8d10-a95c8f5b8041 /media/rich/Hitachi180G ext4 noauto,user,exec,sync,rw,errors=remount-ro  0 4 
#
# swap partition on 2TB Hitachi drive (now on USB) is not in use now. (a logical ptn) 
#  /dev/sdd6 Jan2017
# do not mount
#### UUID=3109e50b-8e0e-434b-a67c-ad3a2af31407 none             swap noauto,noexec,sync  0 5 
# 
#
# partition on 1TB WD Elements drive (now on USB in enclosure) 
# is Elements (a primary ptn) (611 GB). /dev/sdb1 Jan 2017
# shared with Windows in dual boot 
# Use noAuto: Allow Ubuntu to mount via daemon, or manually,
# without possibly booting to emergency mode if disk is not present
UUID=02E43955E4394BE3 /media/rich/Elements ntfs noauto,user,noexec,sync,rw,errors=remount-ro  0 6
#
# partition on 1TB WD Elements drive (now on USB) is Win7Reco  (a primary ptn) (105 GB)
# used only by Windows in dual boot. /dev/sdb3 Jan 2017
# do not mount
# UUID=0BB34DE90D182944 /media/rich/Win7Reco ntfs noauto,noexec,sync,ro  0 7
#
# partition on 1TB WD Elements drive (USB external disk) is Elem281 (a logical ptn) (281 GB)
# Use noAuto: Allow Ubuntu to mount via daemon, or manually,
# without possibly booting to emergency mode if disk is not present. /dev/sdb5 Jan 2017.
UUID=aef29caf-24d1-43e2-a862-9a702f49ce07 /media/rich/Elem281 ext4 noauto,user,exec,sync,rw,errors=remount-ro  0 8
#
# swap partition on 1TB WD Elements drive (USB external disk) is not in use now. (a logical ptn) 
# /dev/sdb6 Jan 2017.
# do not mount.
# UUID=97883275-6988-4c81-9c2f-2534907b2875 none              swap noauto,noexec,sync  0 9
```

```
i@memine-755:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="AA0673D90673A54B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="23a841d3-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="C80277B30277A4DA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="23a841d3-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="e1995ccc-4c3a-45f2-a3b5-41e6b09280f8" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="23a841d3-03"
/dev/sda5: UUID="d381bb29-4376-4c46-ab65-bf922f3be7a9" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="23a841d3-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="dda8beaa-2c0a-451d-a390-e5a82c6a4ce8" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="23a841d3-06"
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="ae4518d0-d0fe-417e-883d-daf012b17198"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Seagate Backup Plus Drive" UUID="C6E600FFE600F18B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="f5c02f78-aa1c-403d-8aed-4551cfd97edb"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="Primary33" UUID="ceae5c96-c593-499d-adaa-7a3559a14b45" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Primary3300" PARTUUID="265b22b8-d826-4384-8784-b2b8246107c5"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Elements" UUID="02E43955E4394BE3" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0004af75-01"
/dev/sdc3: LABEL="Win7Reco" UUID="0BB34DE90D182944" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0004af75-03"
/dev/sdc5: LABEL="Elem281" UUID="aef29caf-24d1-43e2-a862-9a702f49ce07" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0004af75-05"
/dev/sdc6: UUID="97883275-6988-4c81-9c2f-2534907b2875" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="0004af75-06"
i@memine-755:~$
```

Comment: can you add the stuff in `/etc/fstab`  and the output of  `sudo blkid` run from a terminal to your post .. .. you can check `sudo blkid` which should give you a list of drives/partitions connected with their UUIDS .. check the fstab and the UUIDS to make sure that sda3 is listed properly. Sounds like something may be wrong with trying to mount sda3. .. or .. what is sda3 .. are you sure that the drive isn't failing?  .. all this is guesses because of the lack of information but it may help point us in the right direction if you can add that information